# Prompt agent for acceptance before dequeuing an incoming call

Tags: node.js, twilio

I've set up a basic workflow on Twilio/node.js, that will transfer an incoming call to agents' phones. Because the agents might have a voicemail setup on their phone/cell phone, I wanted to prompt them for acceptance through a "gather" instruction. If they press 1, then the call will be transferred ("dequeue" instruction). Otherwise, the reservation is to be rejected.

My problem is that I don't know how to order the instructions: if I gather before enqueuing, then gather doesn't seem to know yet "who to ask". But if enqueue before gathering, then the prompt message will be heard by the caller (incoming client) and it will be too late to reject the reservation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In this case you should not respond to the assignment callback with "dequeue". Instead, you should [use the "call" instruction to initiate a call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/handling-assignment-callbacks#initiating-call) to the agent instead.

With the call instruction you include a URL that will be requested when the call connects to the agent. At this point you should read out your message and use [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) to ensure the agent is ready for the call. When the agent presses a button or the `<Gather>` times out, the `action` attribute of the `<Gather>` will be requested. Then, if you find the user did enter a digit, by checking the [`Digits` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-action-parameters) you can respond with TwiML to [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) the [`<Queue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/queue). In order to dial the actual caller that the reservation refers to, you need to add the [`reservationSid` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/queue#attributes-reservationSid) to the `<Queue>` element. You will receive the [`ReservationSid` as a parameter in the task assignment webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/handling-assignment-callbacks#assignment-callback-parameters). When the call bridges it will accept the reservation.

If the `<Gather>` times out, then you should just reject the reservation and it will be passed to the next worker.

Let me know if that helps at all.

**Edit**

Example TwiML for this situation.

You first respond to the assignment callback with JSON, using a call instruction:

```
{
  "instruction": "call",
  "to": AGENT_PHONE_NUMBER,
  "from": YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER,
  "url": "https://example.com/worker_call?ReservationSid=${req.body.ReservationSid}&TaskSid=${req.body.TaskSid}"
}
```

Note, I have added the `ReservationSid` and `TaskSid` from the incoming request to the URL of the webhook that is called when the worker answers their phone.

Then when the worker answers their phone Twilio calls to the `url` we set above and we use it to ask them if they want to take the call.

```
# /worker_call
<Response>
  <Gather action="/gather_result?ReservationSid=${req.query.ReservationSid}&TaskSid=${req.query.TaskSid}" numDigits="1">
    <Say voice="alice">You have an incoming call, dial any number to accept</Say>
  </Gather>
  <Redirect>/gather_result?ReservationSid=${req.query.ReservationSid}&TaskSid=${req.query.TaskSid}</Redirect>
</Response>
```

Note, I am passing the `ReservationSid` and `TaskSid` along from the incoming request URL to the URL of the `<Gather>` action. Now, when the action URL is called we need to respond based on whether the call was accepted or not. I need to use some actual code for this rather than just TwiML, so I'll do it with Node. We need to be able to call the reservations resource in the REST API, so this comes with some setup:

```
const accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const workspaceSid = 'WSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const twilio = require('twilio')
const client = twilio(accountSid, authToken);

app.post('/gather_result', function(req, res) {
  const twiml = new twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  if (req.body.Digits && req.body.Digits.length > 0) {
    // There was a positive result, call the Queue and connect the caller
    const dial = twiml.dial();
    dial.queue({queue: req.query.ReservationSid});
    res.send(twiml.toString());
  } else {
    // no response, reject the reservation.
    client.taskrouter.v1
      .workspaces(workspaceSid)
      .tasks(req.query.TaskSid)
      .reservations(req.query.ReservationSid)
      .update({ reservationStatus: 'rejected' })
      .then(function() {
        // once the reservation is updated, then hangup the call.
        twiml.hangup();
        res.send(twiml.toString());
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: Makes sense. I'll try it out. Thanks!

Comment: Hi philnash, do you have any example TwiML for doing the patching of the call, and accepting it?

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I've got myself to pretty much this stage, however I don't seem to be receiving a `ReservationSid` into my "prompt for input" step. I'm using AzureFunctions, I can't seem to see the `ReservationSid` anywhere in the request body; should I expect to?

Comment: Oops, think I started passing the `ReservationSid` along too late. Need to pass it in the URL returned in the original assignment instruction. I've edited my answer again.

Comment: Got it working. So... I may have been trying to retrieve the `ReservationSid` from the request body, and not from the query parameters on the URL....

Comment: philnash, think you have an error in your Twiml for asking for input. If no input is entered, the call will just end. You should put in a `<Redirect>` to the same destination and this will allow for your "no digits entered" logic to be captured.

Comment: I get this error if the caller hangs up before the call gets bridged I guess:

14217 - Dial->Queue: Could not find or accept provided reservationSid

Comment: Hi @SimonLudwig, if you are having problems I would ask a new question, describe what you are doing, what you expect to happen and what is actually happening. It is difficult to dig into something new in the comments of a 4 year old answer.